# Why can't use '->' c++ template class

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename E>
class NodeList {
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        E elem;
    };
public:
    Node* begin() const;
    NodeList();
public:
    Node* header;
    Node* trailer;
    int size;
};

template <typename E>
NodeList<E>::NodeList(){
    size = 0;
    header = new Node;
    trailer = new Node;

    header->
    trailer->

}
```

I want to use member variables of NodeList class, but can't use it.

such as `header->next` or `trailer-> prev`

'->' why?

I wonder why can't use it!

sorry I revised it!

from

`header->trailer`

to

`header->next`

when I type '->' then Nothing action like next, prev, elem

Comment: If you're expecting something like Java's "inner" classes, C++ does not work like that.

Comment: Hang on. Are you asking why intellisense doesn't suggest anything, or do you actually get an error *when building*?

Comment: Please show an actual error message. Your example looks like you expect your autocompletion to suggest you things and are confused why it does not. That is just your autocompletion being unhelpful, it has no influence on whether your code is correct.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes intellisense doen’t suggetst anything

Comment: @MaxLanghof intellisense : No members available

Comment: That's an intellisense problem. Intellisense may mess up occasionally. That does not mean your code is wrong. But what matters in the end is if your code can be compiled, not if intellisense has good suggestions. If you get a **compiler** error (i.e. not something with intellisense), please show that (and any associated code).

Answer (score 4):

Well, `header` is a property of `NodeList` and is a pointer to a `Node`.

A `Node` doesn't have headers or tailers, it just has `prev` and `next`. So you can use `header->next` and `trailer->prev` if you want.

Comment: sorry I revised it